# Py.test No module named *

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder structure like this

```
App
--App
  --app.py       
--Docs
--Tests
  --test_app.py
```

In my `test_app.py file`, I have a line to import my app module. When I run py.test on the root folder, I get this error about no module named app. How should I configure this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

Comment: I encounter with this problem. I have to remove my unit test classes & clear the cache using the `--cache-clear` `pytest` flag to solved the error. The problem happends to me when I modify import statements on a class that I was testing. At this point in time I do not know the exact reason about this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So you are running `py.test` from `/App`. Are you sure `/App/App` is in your `$PYTHONPATH`?

If it's not, code that tries to `import app` will fail with such a message.

*EDIT0:* including the info from my comment below, for completeness.

An attempt to import app will only succeed if it was executed inside `/App/App`, which is not the case here. You probably want to make `/App/App` a package by putting `__init__.py` inside it, and change your import to qualify app as `from App import app`.

*EDIT1:* by request, adding further explanation from my second comment below.

By putting `__init__.py` inside `/App/App`, that directory becomes a package. Which means you can import from it, as long as it - the directory - is visible in the `$PYTHONPATH`. I.e. you can do from `App import app` if `/App` is in the `$PYTHONPATH`. Your current working directory gets automatically added to `$PYTHONPATH`, so when you run a script from `/App`, the import will work.

Comment: I have run `pip install -e .` on `/App`, so the package is installed to the `/usr/local` library. I would think this adds my folder to the path?

Comment: There's no reason for `/App/App` to automatically be added into the `$PYTHONPATH`, regardless of where you installed `pip`. An attempt to `import app` will only succeed if it was executed *inside* `/App/App`, which is not the case here. You probably want to make `/App/App` a package by putting `__init__.py` inside it, and change your import to qualify `app` as `from App import app`.

Comment: My test can be ran now. I am still confused about the $PYTHONPATH part. Is it that if I add __init__.py to my `/App/App` folder, python will automatically insert the `/App/App` folder into the path?

Comment: @zsljulius: by putting `__init__.py` inside `/App/App`, that directory becomes a package. Which means you can import from it, as long as it - the directory - is visible in the `$PYTHONPATH`. I.e. you can do `from App import app` if `/App` is in the `$PYTHONPATH`. Your current working directory gets automatically added to `$PYTHONPATH`, so when you run a script from `/App`, the import will work.

Answer (score 208):

Working with Python 3 and getting the same error on a similar project layout, I solved it by adding an `__init__` file to my `tests` module.

```
$ touch tests/__init__.py
```

I'm not great at packaging and importing, but I think that this helps `pytest` work out where the target `App` module is located.

Comment: Before using this strategy, you should check the implications against pytest's best practices: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules

Comment: This is the only way I could make it work in Python 3.

Comment: @jamesc I am following their "best practice" of the "outside app code" pattern and it works if I execute `coverage run -m pytest` or `python -m pytest` but fails if I run `pytest` directly with failed to load module errors.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Really glad to see your comment here as I was stumped for a moment.  I'm unsure if this is the same issue, but I've commented on GitHub: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/6370#issuecomment-575423003

Comment: @blong I've since resolved the problem I was running into by installing my source as a package into the virtual environment which required a deep foray into python packaging and distutils/setuptools.

Comment: confirm_ this works only as @burszely suggested

Comment: Thank you @jamesc so much. Was struggling with this. So dumb!

Answer (score 105):

I already had an `__init__.py` file in the `/App/App` directory and wanted to run tests from the project root without any path-mangling magic:

```
 python -m pytest tests
```

The output immediately looks like this:

```
➟  python -m pytest tests
====================================== test session starts ======================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.1, pytest-2.9.0, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/andrew/code/app, inifile: 
plugins: teamcity-messages-1.17
collected 46 items 

... lines omitted ...

============================= 44 passed, 2 skipped in 1.61 seconds ==============================
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out the reason why launching `py.test` directly fails to discover the `/App/App`?

Comment: well python does add the current directory to the pythonpath, so you are still using path-mangling magic, btw that's why it works!

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar problem and had to delete `__init__.py` from the root and add an `__init__.py` to the `tests` folder.

Comment: I had the same problem and needed to delete the __init__ from the root.  Does anyone know why __init__ in root would cause havoc to pytest?

Comment: I had __init__.py under src/app/ and adding another to src/tests/ worked for me, no idea why.

Answer (score 39):

Running `pytest` with the `python -m pytest` command helps with this exact thing.

Since your current package is not yet in your `$PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` - pytest gets this error.

By using `python -m pytest` you automatically add the working directory into `sys.path` for running `pytest`. Their documentation also mentions:

> This is almost equivalent to invoking the command line script `pytest`

Comment: the best answer for python 3.8

Comment: It is the same for me. I had __init__.py but it still did not work. While I found out `python -m pytest .` works, I could not figure it out why `pytest . ` does not work. Thanks for a good and brief explanation.

Answer (score 14):

I also got same error while running test cases for my app located as below

```
myproject
  --app1
    --__init.py__
    --test.py
  --app2
    --__init.py__
    --test.py
  --__init.py__
```

I deleted my **myproject's** ****init.py**** file to run my test cases.

Comment: Worked for me in Pycharm

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR

You might as well add an empty `conftest.py` file to your root app folder.

*(if you take a look at the question folder structure, that would be the same level as the "Tests" folder, not inside of it)*.

### More info:

Pytest looks for `conftest.py` files inside all your project folders.

`conftest.py` provides configuration for the file tree pytest finds it in. Because pytest somehow scans all subdirectories starting from conftest.py folder, it should find packages/modules outside the tests folder (as long as a conftest.py file is in your app root folder).

Eventually, you might want to write some code in your empty conftest.py, specially to share fixtures among different tests files, in order to avoid duplicate code. Afterall, the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) should also be follwed when writing tests.

Adding `__init.py__` to the tests folder also should help pytest to find  modules throughout your application. However, note that Python 3.3+ has implicit namespace packages that allow it to create a packages without an `__init__.py` file. That been said, creating `__init__.py` files for this specific purpose seems more like a a workaround for pytest than a python requirement. More about that in: [Is __init__.py not required for packages in Python 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)

Comment: Adding `conftest.py` to the root folder helped.

root
   units_under_tests
   tests
   conftest.py

Without conftest.py in the place got the error when running pytest from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar issue. And after trying multiple things including installing pytest on virtual environment and adding/removing `__init__.py` file from the package, none worked for me.

Solution that worked for me is(windows solution):
Added Project folder(not package folder) to python path(set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%CD%)

Ran my script from Project Folder and boom, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same issue.

```
my-app
--conf
--my-app
--tests
```

I set the `__init__.py` files.  I added a `conftest.py` ( for sharing `pytest.fixtures` ).  I added this to my Poetry file ( `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "."
```

Turned out it was my use of hyphens and not underscores !  Noo...

```bash
# pytest can't find Module
--my-app

# works
--my_app
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the following project structure

```
myproject
      manage.py
      pyproject.toml
      --apps
        --app1
        --app2
      --tests
        --apps
          -- app1
          -- app2
      --config
         --settings
            base.py
            local.py
```

Adding **init**.py did not help. I was able to solve the issue by adding the following to pyproject.toml

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "config.settings.local"
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is very simple: set PYTHONPATH environment variable to . (current directory).

```bash
# Windows
set PYTHONPATH=.

# Linux 
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me: I had to make absolute imports in my test file and call `python -m test` in the root folder.

Comment: This runs the regression test package and not pytest: https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html

Comment: I don't get why this called my test modules then...

Comment: For it worked with `python -m pytest`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have an `__init__(self)` method in your testcase.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the **init**.py within the tests directory:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./App'))
```

Whilst calling from the Root App directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and had trouble finding an answer that worked for me. This was my project structure:

```
project_root
  app_folder
    file_under_test1.py
    file_under_test2.py
  tests
    tests_for_file1.py
    tests_for_file2.py
  Dockerfile
  helmvalues.yml
  pytest.ini
```

I followed the advice in one of the early comments to look at pytest's recommendations: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules, thanks @jamesc

This lead me to add the following to my pytest.ini, then things worked:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = app_folder
```

Then I was able to just run `$ pytest` in my project_root and the imports in the test files worked.  I was able to import in my test files in the same way I did the imports in my app files.

I did not have to add `__init__.py` files anywhere either.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:
Went to parent app, and `pip install -e .` (install a local and editable app).