# py.test doesn't find module

Tags: python, pytest

This question is related to the following questions, but is not answered there:

- [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)
- [Py.test No module named *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985157/py-test-no-module-named)

I have a python module with the following tree structure:

```
mcts
|- setup.py
|- mcts
 |- __init__.py
 |- uct.py
 |- toy_world_state.py
 |- test
  |- test_uct.py
  |- test_toy_world_state.py
```

I create a virtualenv in some directory

```
$ mkdir virtual
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages virtual
$ source virtual/bin/activate
```

I then install my package:

```
$ cd /path/to/mcts
$ pip install -e .
```

Now I try to run the tests:

```
$ py.test mcts
================================================== test session starts ==================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.2 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
collected 0 items / 2 errors 

======================================================== ERRORS =========================================================
__________________________________ ERROR collecting mcts/test/test_toy_world_state.py ___________________________________
mcts/test/test_toy_world_state.py:4: in <module>
    from mcts.toy_world_state import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'mcts'
________________________________________ ERROR collecting mcts/test/test_uct.py _________________________________________
mcts/test/test_uct.py:4: in <module>
    from mcts.uct import *
E   ImportError: No module named 'mcts'
================================================ 2 error in 0.02 seconds ===============================================
```

If I go to any path and try to import the module in `ipython` it works:

```
$ cd
$ ipython

In [1]: import mcts.uct

In [2]: mcts.uct? 
Type:        module
String form: <module 'mcts.uct' from '/home/johannes/src/mcts/mcts/uct.py'>
File:        /home/johannes/src/mcts/mcts/uct.py
Docstring:   <no docstring>
```

If I run pytest from within pycharm it works. (But I don't know what magic happens in pycharm...)

While `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns an empty string, the `sys.path` seems to be correct:

```
>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['/home/johannes/src/mcts/virtualenvs/teste/lib/python3.4/site-packages', 
'/home/johannes/src/mcts', '', '/usr/bin', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py3.4.egg', 
'/usr/lib/python34.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.4', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/extensions', 
'/home/johannes/.ipython']
```

What do I have to do, to get the pytests running?

Comment: I can't see a module `toy_world_state` within your file structure which may explain why `from mcts.toy_world_state import *` throws an error.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my question. I change that.

Comment: I wonder if you add the project to your `$PYTHONPATH` this might work and might be exactly what PyCharm is configured to do.

Comment: shouldn't do `pip install -e .` do that? (resp. add the package to the `site-package` directory of the virtualenv -- which should be in `$PYTHONPATH`)

Comment: Btw. if I do `PYTHONPATH=. py.test mcts` it works. If I do `PYTHONPATH=./virtualenvs/teste/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ py-test mcts` it does not. I'm totally confused.

Comment: From your description (pretty complete btw), I can't see anything wrong with your setup. Can you provide a working example in a public repository?

Comment: it is already in one. Just ignore the implementation of mcts and uct: http://github.com/hildensia/mcts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed it myself. For some reason pytest did not got the virtualenv correct. Installing pytest in the virtualenv solved it

```
source virtualenvs/teste/bin/activate
pip install pytest
```

Answer (score 6):

I created this as an answer to your question and my own confusion. I hope it helps. Pay attention to PYTHONPATH in both the py.test command line and in the tox.ini.

https://github.com/jeffmacdonald/pytest_test

Specifically: You have to tell py.test and tox where to find the modules you are including.

With py.test you can do this:

```
PYTHONPATH=. py.test
```

And with tox, add this to your tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
deps= -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
commands=py.test
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
```

Comment: Please read this post by fellow Stack Overflow community moderator before  creating more posts about your project: [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Answer (score -3):

Your error message says:

> ImportError: No module named 'mcts'

Looking at the directory structure you provided, that error is telling you that you don't have an 'mcts' module/package. To fix it, you need to add an "__init__.py" file to the 'mcts' directory. Afterwards, you should be able to run 'py.test' without other arguments/settings.