# How to solve ImportError with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package)  [were](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985157/py-test-no-module-named) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446418/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-main-xxxx-main-is-not-a-packag/52756937) questions regarding this topic. Sometimes programmers put some `__init__.py` at some places, often it is said one should use absolute paths. However, I don't get it to work here:

How do I import a class from a package so that tests in pytest run and the code can be used?

At the moment I get pytest or the code passing respective running.

My example project structure is

```
.
├── testingonly
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── testingonly.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_testingonly.py
```

`__init__.py` is in both cases an empty file.

```
$ cat testingonly/cli.py
"""Console script for testingonly."""
from testingonly import Tester

def main(args=None):
    """Console script for testingonly."""
    te = Tester()
    return 0

main()
```

```
$ cat testingonly/testingonly.py
"""Main module."""
class Tester():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello")
```

This gives - as expected:

```
$ python3 testingonly/cli.py
Hello
```

Trying to test this, however, fails:

```
$ pytest
========================================================= test session starts =========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/stefan/Development/testingonly
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                           

=============================================================== ERRORS ================================================================
_____________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_testingonly.py ______________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/stefan/Development/testingonly/tests/test_testingonly.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_testingonly.py:10: in <module>
    from testingonly import cli
testingonly/cli.py:2: in <module>
    from testingonly import Tester
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Tester' from 'testingonly' (/home/stefan/Development/testingonly/testingonly/__init__.py)
```

---

Renaming `testingonly/testingonly.py` to `testingonly/mytest.py` and changing the imports in test_testingonly.py (from testingonly import mytest) and cli.py (from mytest import Tester) gives

```
$ pytest
========================================================= test session starts =========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/stefan/Development/testingonly
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                           

=============================================================== ERRORS ================================================================
_____________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_testingonly.py ______________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/stefan/Development/testingonly/tests/test_testingonly.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_testingonly.py:10: in <module>
    from testingonly import cli
testingonly/cli.py:2: in <module>
    from mytest import Tester
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mytest'
======================================================= short test summary info =======================================================
ERROR tests/test_testingonly.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================== 1 error in 0.37s ===========================================================
$ python3 testingonly/cli.py
Hello
```

---

The other proposed solution with renaming to mytest.py lets the tests pass, but in cli.py using `from testingonly.mytest import Tester` gives a *NameNotFound* error.

```
$ python3 testingonly/cli.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingonly/cli.py", line 2, in <module>
    from testingonly.mytest import Tester
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testingonly'
```

```
$ pytest
========================================================= test session starts =========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/stefan/Development/testingonly
collected 1 item                                                                                                                      

tests/test_testingonly.py .                                                                                                     [100%]

========================================================== 1 passed in 0.12s ==========================================================
```

Comment: This answer on relative Python Imports may help as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183205/importing-a-module-in-nested-packages

Comment: First of all, `from testingonly import Tester` is wrong. The `Tester` class is defined in module with qualname `testingonly.testingonly` as is not exported in `testingonly/__init__.py`, so the import will not resolve. It works in `testingonly.cli` only because it is on the same level as `testingonly.testingonly`, with a relative import as fallback. To verify, create some `foo.py` in the root dir with a single line `from testingonly import Tester` and run `python foo.py` - you will get the same error.

Comment: Second, `pytest` doesn't add the project root dir to `sys.path` by default - you should take care of it yourself. Either run `python -m pytest`, or add an empty file named `conftest.py` to the project root dir. Check out the answers in [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10253826/2650249) for more details.

Comment: Ah, and the correct replacement for `from testingonly import Tester` is of course `from testingonly.testingonly import Tester`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The self-named module `testingonly` and file name of  `testingonly.py` may be causing some issues with the way the modules are imported.

Remove the `__init__.py` from the `tests` directory. [Ref this answer .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Try renaming `testingonly.py` to `mytest.py` and then importing it into your project again.

In the `cli.py`, it should be:

```
from testingonly.mytest import Tester
```

And then for your test file `test_testingonly.py`:

```
from testingonly.mytest import Tester
```

You're `test_testingonly.py` file should look like this:

```
import pytest
from testingonly.mytest import Tester  # Import the Tester Class


def test_tester(capsys):
    # Create the Tester Class
    te = Tester()
    # Get the captured output
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    # Assert that the capture output is tested
    assert captured.out == "Hello\n"
```

Finally, Run your tests with:

```
python -m pytest tests/
```

Here is a fully working example based off of your code: https://github.com/cdesch/testingonly

Comment: I updated my question with the ```from mytest import Tester``` try. The other one gives an error with pytest. To be added soon...

Comment: Did you get it to work? I saw you accepted the answer.

Comment: Yes, it did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: Sry, it did not do the trick. This always happens to me at the moment, I get confused with what I tested an what not...rewrite the question.

Comment: If you can post the sample code on github, I can take a look.

Comment: I posted a sample on github that works with your Code. I also added a `MyCalc` class into the project to show another class being tested. Here is the code: https://github.com/cdesch/testingonly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240723/discussion-between-stefan-bollmann-and-dogeatdog).

Comment: I discovered that using pytest . failed but using python -m pytest . works

Answer (score 3):

This is only a python path issue. Your pytest is unable to find the path to source modules.

One way to fix this: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.` before running pytest. Here you are saying that your current folder represented by a dot is a python module path. This is what happens when you also run via `python -m pytest`, where the module path gets set automatically.

But this requires you to set the `PYTHONPATH` every time before you run pytest, or use a long command for pytest which is very inconvenient.

One earlier method to overcome this issue: install [pytest-pythonpath](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pythonpath/) plugin to automatically add `PYTHONPATH` to environment. This module is obsolete now (as seen in its home page) because pytest.ini allows you to specify python path directly from v7 onwards

So now all you have to do is this: ensure that your pytest is version 7 or above, and your pytest.ini file should contain these lines:

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
pythonpath = .
```

Now your pytest will have no trouble finding your source modules. You may also add your source folders to `pythonpath` in pytest.ini if required

pytest documentation for pythonpath: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath

Comment: Update your `PYTHONPATH` in the `venv` `activate` script. I presume this is what IDEs always do anyway. It seems IDEs can do whatever crap they like and no-one calls it a hack, and then they say something like "ooh have you tried PyCharm it's so cool". Then they start complaining about "works for me" inconsistency problems.