# Gitlab CI does not recognize Python on Windows

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to run py.test within the root of my repository(it runs fine when locally)

I have already set my environment variables for Python and Git (they work fine), and my CI runner connects with my gitlab repo. However, when a build is triggered I get this message:

> gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.3.1 (4911137)
>   Using Shell executor...
>   Running on XXXXXX...
>
> Fetching changes...
>
> HEAD is now at 1aa2135 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
>   Checking out 1aa21352 as cirunner...
>
> $ py.test
>
> 'py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> ERROR: Build failed: exit status 9009

Why would the Shell Executor not recognize Python/py.test ?
This is on Windows Server 2012.

EDIT: I want to run unit tests with py.test everytime I push to remote

Comment: I'm confused, what are you trying to accomplish, is this a python script that you're trying to run?

Comment: I just want to run unit tests(with py.test) on my project every time I push to remote

Comment: is the thing that is trying to run the python script using the right directory?  Maybe you need to specify a full path for `py.test`

Comment: @mugizico have you tried using the `python` command? Is `python` in your env variables? Have you ever ran a `python` script on the machine your on?

Comment: @Wolf that Worked!! thanks a bunch. I had to give it a full path to py.test so `C:\Users\myuser\python3\scripts\py.test`

Comment: @13aal  yes, yes, and yes if you read my question again, I already mentioned that running the script locally works just fine. the CI runner was the one causing the problem

Answer (score 4):

I know it's one year late but might be useful for other people.
You can set variables in your gitlab-ci.yml.
Then you just have to set your PATH variable with the path to your python binaries like this :

```
variables:
  PATH: "C:\\Python27"
```

and then you can use the `python` command in any of your jobs

```
test:
  script:
    - python unittest.py
    - python regressiontest.py
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost similarly to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada) I just had to give the `script` in .gitlab-ci.yml a full path to py.test like so:

> Script:
>     - C:\Users\Admin\Python3\scripts\py.test

instead of

> Script:
>      - py.test

and it worked