# pytest cannot import module while python can

Tags: python, import, pytest

I am working on a package in Python. I use virtualenv. I set the path to the root of the module in a .pth path in my virtualenv, so that I can import modules of the package while developing the code and do testing (Question 1: is it a good way to do?). This works fine  (here is an example, this is the behavior I want):

```
(VEnvTestRc) zz@zz:~/Desktop/GitFolders/rc$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rc import ns
>>> exit()
(VEnvTestRc) zz@zz:~/Desktop/GitFolders/rc$ python tests/test_ns.py 
issued command: echo hello
command output: hello
```

However, if I try to use PyTest, I get some import error messages:

```
(VEnvTestRc) zz@zz:~/Desktop/GitFolders/rc$ pytest
=========================================== test session starts ============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/zz/Desktop/GitFolders/rc, inifile: 
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

================================================== ERRORS ==================================================
________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_ns.py ________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/zz/Desktop/GitFolders/rc/tests/test_ns.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_ns.py:2: in <module>
    from rc import ns
E   ImportError: cannot import name ns
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================= 1 error in 0.09 seconds ==========================================
(VEnvTestRc) zz@zz:~/Desktop/GitFolders/rc$ which pytest
/home/zz/Desktop/VirtualEnvs/VEnvTestRc/bin/pytest
```

I am a bit puzzled, it looks like this indicates an import error, but Python does it fine so why is there a problem specifically with PyTest? Any suggestion to the reason / remedy (Question 2)? I googled and stack-overflowed the 'ImportError: cannot import' error for PyTest, but the hits I got were related to missing python path and remedy to this, which does not seem to be the problem here. Any suggestions?

Comment: This also might be some missing import issue

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Found the answer:

DO NOT put a `__init__.py` file in a folder containing TESTS if you plan on using pytest. I had one such file, deleting it solved the problem.

This was actually buried in the comments to the second answer of [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada) so I did not see it, hope it gets more visibility here.

Comment: Funny. I had the same issue and I had to add __init__.py to my tests folder.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a general solution (even though it was in your case), to understand why this should be read: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-package-name

Comment: This information is WRONG and misleading! After adding __init__.py into the test folder everything worked fine

Comment: @LeonardoOstan it may be wrong for you, but it doesn't mean this information is wrong in general. In my case it solved the issue.

Comment: This is wrong now. My tests are located in `project_root/tests/` and source code in `project_root/myapp/`, I placed an init file in `project_root/tests/__init__.py` to be able to import the helper module `project_root/tests/helper.py` in `project_root/tests/test_foo.py`. Inside `project_root/` I can run tests with `python -m pytest -vv tests/`.

Comment: @Zorglub29 very strange as this worked for me as well. when ran locally and in the pipeline. thank you for your observation and suggestion :)

Comment: I had exact issue. And for me, it's exactly the test module naming problem: starts with "test_". To fix it, rename it to avoid lowercased test_

Comment: if you have tests starting wtih test_ in a folder, `__init__.py` shouldn't be there. Otherwise you will get the import errors.

Comment: As the above comment by @Ev.   I had the same issue and I had to add __init__.py to my tests folder to correct it

Comment: I want to be able to run from cmdline the `tests.*` files in the `tests` directory. So it would seem that `__init__.py` were needed. So this solution is not a good one for me

Comment: I followed this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400391/1056563 that sayss to remove `__init__.py` from the **project** root directory. That works for me and without introducing additional usability issues.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works?

Comment: This works using poetry `poetry run python -m pytest tests/`

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 203):

I can't say I understand why this works, but I had the same problem and the tests work fine if I run `python -m pytest`.

I'm in a virtualenv, with pytest also available globally:

```
(proj)tom@neon ~/dev/proj$ type -a python
python is /home/tom/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python

(proj)tom@neon ~/dev/proj$ python -V
Python 3.5.2

(proj)tom@neon ~/dev/proj$ type -a pytest
pytest is /home/tom/.virtualenvs/proj/bin/pytest
pytest is /usr/bin/pytest

(proj)tom@neon ~/dev/proj$ pytest --version
This is pytest version 3.5.0, imported from /home/tom/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytest.py
```

Comment: Also did the job for me, the thing is,, it's get run by the python version defined instead of your v.env.

Comment: one reason might be that `python -m pytest [...]` "will also add the current directory to `sys.path`."

Comment: Had the same in Windows 10, and running python -m pytest solved it

Comment: This worked for as well inside my virtual environment I had to run `python3 -m pytest`

Comment: Based on the comment by @minusf I'm using `PYTHONPATH=.:./src pytest` as a make target.

Comment: `python -m pytest` runs a `__main__.py` file while calling a module directly uses `__init__.py`. The poster's problem is that he has an `__init__.py` in his tests directory

Comment: +1 In my case i also had to cd in app (src) directory from root dir where are stored global settings, docker files and etc.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Deactivating and Reactivating my virtualenv solved the issue for me. You don't have to do python -m pytest.

Answer (score 82):

I just solved this by removing the `__init__.py` in my project root:

```
.
├── __init__.py <--- removed
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── address.py
│   ├── appointment.py
│   └── client.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── appointment_test.py
│   │   └── client_test.py
│   └── other_test.py
└── script.py
```

Comment: The accepted answer `__init__.py file in a folder containing TESTS` did not solve my problem. This one worked. I guess it's because of the file hierarchy.

Comment: I have removed ```__init__.py``` file. I was still facing issue. Adding conftest.py file to the root directory worked for me.

Comment: I'd expect conftest.py to be in /tests not the root

Comment: Getting the conftest.py file to the root directory also fixed it for me. Don't have an __init__.py file in the tests directory

Comment: This solution worked for me but does anyone know this would cause an import error?

Comment: Accidentally there was a init file in my root folder which caused the `pytest` to misbehave. After removing it worked.

Comment: This was also what fixed it for me! In my case I think the issue was also that the my project structure was proj_folder as a root and it had two children proj_folder/project_folder and proj_folder/tests (so same name for project root and subdirectory). So then in one of the test files in test i  had an import like: from proj_folder import main. Now, because I had an init in the project root, pytest was attempting to get a main module that was actually in project_folder/project_folder!

Comment: **This**   Many answers said it's necessary to remove `__init__.py` from the `tests` directory - but I don't want that. This solved the problem without introducing additional issues.

Comment: I have no such file in my project root. This is not the answer.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem but for another reason than the ones mentioned:

*I had py.test installed globally, while the packages were installed in a virtual environment.*

The solution was to install `pytest` in the virtual environment. (In case your shell hashes executables, as Bash does, use `hash -r`, or use the full path to `py.test`)

Comment: Just realized I had the same sneaky issue, using anaconda. I forgot to add `pytest` in the virtualenv created by `conda`, yet `pytest` it is available in anaconda's root environment. Therefore pytest **could** be found, but not any package installed in the environment.

Comment: I had the same issue. pytest was installed globally and not in the virtualenv. `pip3 install pytest` inside virtualenv fixed the issue.

Comment: I even had it installed in my venv but for some reason it wasn't picking it up. (`which pytest` showed the wrong version) Deactivating and reactivating the venv fixed everything.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 38):

Had a similar issue and it worked when I added `__init__.py` file under tests directory.

Comment: And, `conftest.py` as well in my case.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case.

Comment: While running `python -m pytest . ` was able to discover and execute my tests, using VSCode to run tests required adding`__init__.py` so the IDE could discover and run my tests.

Answer (score 33):

Simply put an empty `conftest.py` file in the project root directory, because when `pytest` discovers a `conftest.py`, it modifies `sys.path` so it can import stuff from the `conftest` module.
A general directory structure can be:

```
Root
├── conftest.py
├── module1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── sample.py
└── tests
    └── test_sample.py
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Forget all that `__init__.py` craziness.

Comment: Didn't work for me. All very odd.

Comment: Didn't work for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me. I believe this is the long-term solution for anyone who has it working with `python -m pytest` but doesn't want to add the extra verbiage every time

Answer (score 26):

As of pytest 7.0, you can now add pythonpath in pytest.ini. No need to add `__init__.py` or `conftest.py` in your root directory.

```
[pytest]
minversion = 7.0
addopts = --cov=src
pythonpath = src
testpaths =
    tests
```

You can run `pytest` without any parameters.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.0.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath

**Update:**

Here's a sample repo on how I setup my projects which uses the above config:

https://github.com/ianpogi5/pytest-path

Comment: This is by far the cleanest and most effective answer here. No need to change folder structure; you can keep your tests separated from the src, nice, and clean; no need to bloat your code with sys.path in each single file; is supported officially and well documented; no need to manually edit PATH (which is not easily reproducible by default on other machines); and it works like a charm.

Comment: By far the best answer I found. This should be the content of a community post

Comment: Still doesn't work (pytest 7.3.1). See my answer: `import my_other_file` in `__main__.py` still causes a fail, even when this package contains `__init__.py` (and even when I use these configuration settings in pytest.ini).

Comment: @mikerodent do you have sample github repo?

Comment: Glad you asked. Just done it: https://github.com/Mrodent/pytest_probs/tree/main. On my system this wouldn't clone (SSH problem?) but you can download the .zip. Then see what I say in README.md. Interested to know whether you find the same prob as me... or not!

Comment: @mikerodent You have `assert False` https://github.com/Mrodent/pytest_probs/blob/f049c2c4230b56c70c7064b9e3938bb3b4f0c284/tests/basic_tests/test_basic.py#L27 in your tests that's why all your tests fails. I changed it to `True`, now all tests passed. I also suggest you create venv to isolate your environment. Those are the only 2 things I changed.

Comment: Hahaha. You didn't bother reading my README: "3 out of 4 tests in test_basic will fail, as intended". Now, very importantly, I need an accurate answer to this: in conftest.py, please COMMENT OUT the line "sys.path.insert(0, src_core_dir_path_str)" ... then run "pytest" again, and tell me whether or not you get a ModuleNotFound error. Everything is done in a VE in my setup. In fact this is irrelevant.

Comment: @mikerodent since your code is in `src/core`, set `pythonpath = src/core` in your `pytest.ini`. Your error will be gone.

Comment: That works. But it's then exactly the same as extending sys.path manually in conftest.py! I.e. you have to include, manually, every single directory where you need .py files to be imported into other files. For example, if you have a directory (and module) src/matching you would then have to add "src/matching" to `pythonpath` in pytest.ini. Your answer here obviously implies, wrongly, that `pythonpath=src` will recursively make all directories in the directory tree under src work as they should. Sadly it doesn't do that, which you now know, so you should edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @mikerodent you only need to include the root of your source files which in your case `src/core`. For sub-directories you will always have `__init__.py` in them so they will always work. This is the standard practice for importing files in sub directories. Without it, your app will not run.

Comment: @mikerodent I've created a sample repo which you can use as a reference. The link to the repo is in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73380948/130237).

Comment: That doesn't in fact run (running > python ...) on my machine: I had to get rid of the "dots" on the import lines in `coffee\__main__.py` and coffee\main.py. When I did that I could run as Python, but pytest failed on the line `from americano import americano`: ImportError. There's no point running pytest on something which is not valid, runnable Python in the first place. Does this run as Python on your machine? PS we probably need to move to chat ...

Comment: @mikerodent It runs without issues even on [github action](https://github.com/ianpogi5/pytest-path/actions). Works with python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11. I got more than 30 projects using the same structure, many different devs and deployment machines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255013/discussion-between-ian-and-mike-rodent).

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me!

However, it complaint that `addopts = --cov=src` could not reconize.  removed it and worked fine (wihtout relative imports)

Answer (score 22):

***2024-02-10 PATH AND VISIBILITY MYSTERIES EXPLAINED***

I originally answered this in October 2021. I had struggled with this problem for ages. As described in my original answer below NONE of the solutions here worked. Over 2 years I got 24 upvotes (and 2 downvotes) so it seemed like others were having similar intractable difficulties. I had reluctantly concluded that I had to manipulate `sys.path` to get pytest to be able to "see" the files that I thought it should see.

I was wrong and failed to understand something about paths. And CRUCIALLY this involves the running of a project (as most of my projects are) where the application is run by using this command (in W10):

```
> python src\core
```

In other words, from the start, the CWD is not the current (project root) directory, but a subdirectory [project root directory]\src\core (which contains file `__main__.py`)

This is where the problem arose. If you are not in fact running a file in the root directory of your project you need to be aware that putting the `tests` directory in your root directory will plunge you into a world of pain and bafflement: sibling .py files will bafflingly not be "found" in your main "run" directory, i.e. where CWD is, i.e. by virtue of your command line.

Instead, in my case, I need the **root "tests" directory to be a subdirectory of src\core** (relative to the root directory of my project).

As a more general rule: wherever the CWD of your project is as you run it as an application is the place where you must put your "tests" directory.

Hope this helps someone.

-------------- MY ORIGINAL NAIVE, INCORRECT ANSWER OF 2021-10:

***ANOTHER SUGGESTION***

I explored this question and various others on SO and elsewhere... all the stuff about adding (or removing) an empty `__init__.py` in  and/or conftest.py in various parts of the project directory structure, all the stuff about PYTHONPATH, etc., etc.: NONE of these solutions worked for me, in what is actually a very simple situation, and which shouldn't be causing any grief.

I regard this as a flaw in pytest's current setup. In fact I got a message recently from someone on SO who clearly knew his stuff. He said that pytest is not designed to work with (as per Java/Groovy/Gradle) separate "src" and "test" directory structures, and that test files should be mingled in amongst the application directories and files. This perhaps goes some way to providing an explanation  ... however, tests, particularly integration/functional tests, don't always necessarily correspond neatly to particular directories, and I think pytest should give users more choice in this regard.

Structure of my project:

```
project_root
    src
        core
            __init__.py
            __main__.py
            my_other_file.py 
    tests
        basic_tests
            test_first_tests.py
```

The import problem posed: very simply, `__main__.py` has a line `import my_other_file`. This (not surprisingly) works OK when I just run the app, i.e. run `python src/core` from the root directory.

But when I run `pytest` with a test which imports `__main__.py` I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_other_file'
```

on the line in `__main__.py` that tries to import "my_other_file". Note that the problem here, in my case, is that, in the course of a pytest test, **one application file fails to find another application file in the same package**.

***USING PYTHONPATH***
After a lot of experimentation, and putting an `__init__.py` file and a confest.py file in just about every directory I could find (I think the crucial files were `__init__.py` added to "tests" and "basic_tests", see above directory structure), and then setting PYTHONPATH to as follows

```
PYTHONPATH=D:\My Documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\my_project\src\core
```

... I found it worked. Imports in the testing files had to be tweaked a bit, the general pattern being `from core import app, project`, but the test files were able to "see" `core`, and crucially there was no need to mess around with the `import` commands in the app files.

HOWEVER... for some reason the tests now run ***much slower*** using this method! Compared to my solution below, where the `core` package can be seen to be loaded just once, my suspicion is that the PYTHONPATH solution probably results in vast amounts of code being reloaded again and again. I can't yet confirm this, but I can't see any other explanation.

***THE ALTERNATIVE***

As I say, I regard this as a flaw in pytest's setup. I have absolutely no idea what pytest does to establish a common-sense setup for `sys.path`, but it's obviously getting it wrong. There should be no need to rely on PYTHONPATH, or whatever, and if indeed this is the "official" solution, the documentation on this subject is **sorely lacking**.

The ONLY working solution, at least on my machines (OS W10 and Linux, as at pytest 7.3.1), is to add the application packages to `sys.path`. It is undesirable to mess with `sys.path`, but in this case nothing else at all works for me.

The most obvious place to do this is `conftest.py`, which gets executed at the start of each pytest run, and which is kept the project root directory. It involves no modification of the app files. Typically (for the above directory/files setup):

```
this_file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__)
src_core_dir_path_str = str(this_file_path.parent.joinpath('src', 'core'))
sys.path.insert(0, src_core_dir_path_str)
```

I am currently (2023-08) using pytest v 7.3.1, and have also tried editing pytest.ini, as suggested by [ian's 2022 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73380948/595305), where it is suggested that these configurations in pytest.ini are a new thing to solve the problem since v7 (release 2021-12). In my machines this does not solve the problem: without manually altering `sys.path` pytest's attempt to import `__main__.py` in my example fails as before: because `import my_other_file` raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_other_file'`.

PS I have now set up a **minimal git repo** illustrating the problem: download the .zip at https://github.com/Mrodent/pytest_probs/tree/main, and read what I say in README.md. Interested to know if anyone gets different results to what I get.

--

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer - it's awesome and so clear! Could you please clarify what exactly to do with the "clunky but effective solution" you provide to fix the permanent sys.path addition? Where can this code be run? After each pytest run?

Comment: "He said that pytest is not designed to work with (as per Java/Groovy/Gradle) separate "src" and "test" directory structures"
This is false. A lot of information in this answer is incorrect and encouraging bad practices, like manipulating sys.path manually,

Answer (score 17):

In my case I am working in a container and unfortuantely pytest has the tendency to use python2.7 rather than my python3 interpreter of choice.

In my case this worked:

```py
python3 -m pytest
```

My folder structure

```
/
app/
-module1.py
-module2.py
-tests/
--test_module1.py
--test_module2.py
requirements.txt
README.md
```

Answer (score 13):

This problem will happen if you have a `tests.py` file and a  tests folder with `tests/__init__.py`.

During the collection pytest finds the folder, but when it tries to import the test files from the folder, `tests.py` file will cause the import problem.

To fix simply remove the `tests.py` file and put all your tests inside the `tests/` folder.

For your specific case the fix will be precisely:

- Remove the file `/home/zz/Desktop/GitFolders/rc/tests.py`
- Make sure `/home/zz/Desktop/GitFolders/rc/tests/__init__.py` is present

Answer (score 10):

I solved my problem by setting the `PYTHONPATH` in Environment Variables for the specific configuration I'm running my tests with.

While you're viewing the test file on PyCharm:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Type `Edit Configurations`
3. Set your `PYTHONPATH` under Environment > Environment variables.

**UPDATE**

1. Move into your project's directory root
2. Create a virtual environment
3. Activate your newly created virtual environment
4. Set the variable `$PYTHONPATH` to the root of your project and export it:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
```

5. Do not remove the `__init__.py` from the `tests/` directory or from the `src/` directory.

Also note:

- The root of your directory is not a python module so do NOT add an `__init__.py`
- `conftest.py` is not necessary in the root of your project.

6. The `$PYTHONPATH` var will only be available during the current terminal/console session; so you will need to set this each time.
   (You can follow the steps previous to this update if you are working in pycharm).

Comment: As an explicit example, I set the `Environment variables:` field in my PyCharm pytest run configuration to `PYTHONPATH=/my_projects_root_dir:$PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: This solved the issue for me:

"The root of your directory is not a python module so do NOT add an __init__.py"

By just removing the __init__.py, got me running again.

Comment: This worked for me. I don't understand why setting the `pythonpath` configuration option doesn't do the trick[1].

Also, in my case I have no __init__.py in the tests folders.

[1]: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, exact same error, but different cause.  I was running the test code just fine, but against an old version of the module. In the previous version of my code one class existed, while the other did not. After updating my code, I should have run the following to install it.

`sudo pip install ./ --upgrade`

Upon installing the updated module running pytest produced the correct results (because i was using the correct code base).

Comment: This worked for me! My module was at the same time installed as a library in the docker container I was using to run pytest. When running the python interpreter it would find the updated code, but pytest would continue to find the code as it was when the library was first installed. 
Running `pip install ./ --upgrade` updated the installed version of the lib with the latest code, and enabled pytest to find this latest version too.

Comment: Same for me, `conda update --all` resolved the problem

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the import error occurred because the package is pointing to another package/directory with the **same name** and its path is one level above the folder I actually wanted.
I think this also explains why some people need to remove _ *init* _.py while others need to add back.

I just put `print(the_root_package.__path__)` (after `import the_root_package`) in both `python` console and `pytest` scripts to compare the **difference**

BOTTOM LINE: When you do `python`, the package you import may be different from the package when you run `pytest`.

Answer (score 7):

Please check here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/documentation-restructure/background/pythonpath.html

I has an issue with pytest (that was solved using `python -m pytest`); the error was

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/...
```

I found the problem was missing `__init__.py` in `tests/` and `tests/subfolders`.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

I had placed all my tests in a tests folder and was getting the same error. I solved this by adding an `__init__.py` in that folder like so:

```
.
|-- Pipfile
|-- Pipfile.lock
|-- README.md
|-- api
|-- app.py
|-- config.py
|-- migrations
|-- pull_request_template.md
|-- settings.py
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py <------
    |-- conftest.py
    `-- test_sample.py
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: what error did you get @mikerodent

Answer (score 5):

Install the packages into Your virtual environment.
Then start a new shell and source Your virtual environment again.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [a medium article](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5)! describing the problem!

The issue is which pytest you are using and your use of a virtual environment.
If you have installed pytest system-wide, in other words, outside of a virtual environment, pytest has a nasty habit of only looking outside your virtual environment for modules! If your project is using a module that is only installed in your virtual environment, and you’re using a system-wide pytest, it won’t find the module, even if you’ve activated the virtual environment.[1](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5)

Here’s the step-by-step:[1](https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5)

1. Exit any virtual environment
2. Use Pip to uninstall pytest
3. Activate your project’s virtual environment
4. Install pytest inside the virtual environment
5. pytest will now find your virtual-environment-only packages!

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

The answer above not work for me. I just solved it by appending the absolute path of the module which not found to the `sys.path` at top of the `test_xxx.py` (your test module), like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path')
```

Comment: Instead of putting these lines at the top of my `test_main.py`, I put it in `conftest.py` in my test directory, and it worked. Thanks for providing a programmatic solution, instead of file litter.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this using VSCode. I have a conda environment. I don't think the VScode python extension could see the updates I was making.

```
python c:\Users\brig\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- -s --cache-clear test
Test Discovery failed:
```

I had to run `pip install ./ --upgrade`

Comment: That pip command returns an error: `Directory './' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.`

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this issue today and solved it by calling `python -m pytest` from the root of my project directory.

Calling `pytest` from the same location still caused issues.

My Project dir is organized as:

```
api/
 - server/
  - tests/
      - test_routes.py
  - routes/
      - routes.py
 - app.py
```

The module `routes` was imported in my `test_routes.py` as: `from server.routes.routes import Routes`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I've had to use the trick in the past and it's in the pytest documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the posts saying that you must remove any `__init__.py` files. What you must instead do is alter the `sys.path`.

Run an experiment where you print `sys.path` when running the code normally.
Then print `sys.path` while running the code via pytest. I think you will find that there is a difference between these two paths, hence why pytest breaks.

To fix this, insert the path from the first experiment at the 0th index of the second.

Let `'/usr/exampleUser/Documents/foo'` be the first element of `print(sys.path)` for experiment 1.

Below is code that should fix your issue:

`import sys
sys.path[0] = '/usr/exampleUser/Documents/foo'`

Put this at the top of your file, before your actual import statement.

Source: I was dealing with this myself and the above process solved it.

Comment: The only solution from listed here that worked for me.

Comment: Yes, even now, version 7.3.1., messing with sys.path appears to be the only solution. Otherwise files are simply unable to import sibling .py files (i.e. in the same directory). Both are indicators that the makers of pytest have a fundamental design flaw here. Or potentially that the correct practice is not properly documented.

Answer (score 3):

Points to be observed in the same order as below:

1. Make sure that every folder and subfolder of your app has a `__init__.py`
   file.
2. Make sure that the tests folder(module) is inside the app folder(module).
3. Try `pytest` command and if that doesn't work try `python3 -m pytest` .

Answer (score 3):

The `TestCase` directory must be a Python Package

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another special case:

I had the problem using tox. So my program ran fine, but unittests via tox kept complaining.
After installing packages (needed for the program) you need to additionally specify the packages used in the unittests in the tox.ini

```
[testenv]
deps =
    package1
    package2 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is related to python code that was originally developed in python 2.7 and now migrated into python 3.x than the problem is probably related to an import issue.

e.g.
when importing an object from a file: `base` that is located in the same directory this will work in python 2.x:

```
from base import MyClass
```

in python 3.x you should replace with `base` full path or `.base`
not doing so will cause the above problem. 
so try:

```
from .base import MyClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another massive win for Python's import system. I think the reason there is no consensus is that what works probably depends on your environment and the tools you are using on top of it.

I'm using this from VS Code, in the test explorer under Windows in a conda environment, Python 3.8.

The setup I have got to work is:

```
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    view.py
tests/
    test_app.py
    test_view.py
```

Under this setup intellisense works and so does test discovery.

Note that I originally tried the following, as recommended [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules).

```
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        view.py
tests/
    test_app.py
    test_view.py
```

I could find no way of getting this to work from VS Code because the `src` folder just blew the mind of the import system. I can imagine there is a way of getting this to work from the command line. As a relatively new convert to Python programming it gives me a nostalgic feeling of working with COM, but being slightly less fun.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents on this: pytest will fail at chance if you are not using virtual environments. Sometimes it will just work, sometimes not.

Therefore, the solution is:

- remove pytest with pip uninstall
- create your venv
- activate your venv
- pip install your project path in editable mode, so it will be treated by pytest as a module (otherwise, pytest wont find your internal imports). You will need a setup.py file for that
- install your packages, including pytest
- finally, run your tests

The code, using windows PowerShell:

```
pip uninstall pytest
python.exe -m venv my_env
.\my_env\Scripts\activate
(my_env) pip install -e .
(my_env) pip install pytest pytest-html pandas numpy
```

Then finally

```
(my_env) pytest --html="my_testing_report.html"
```

An example of setup.py, for pip install -e:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='devel',
    author='erickfis',
    author_email='erickfis@gmail.com',
    description='My package',
    long_description='My gooood package',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Comment: Recreating virtual environment solved the issue for me!

Comment: I have only ever used virtual environments. This is not the solution in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer in there :Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

> If you have other project structure, place the conftest.py in the package root dir (the one that contains packages but is not a package itself, so does not contain an **init**.py)

Answer (score 2):

update PYTHONPATH till src folder

```
export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/pycharm_project_968/src
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who tried everything and still getting error,I have a work around.

In the **folder where pytest is installed**,go to **pytest-env** folder.

Open  **pyvenv.cfg** file.

In the file change **include-system-site-packages** from **false** to **true**.

```
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.6.6
```

Hope it works .Don't forget to up vote.

Comment: No such folder. There's only pytest under site-packages, and no .cfg file. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

**Kept everything same and just added a blank test file at the root folder ..** Solved it

Here are the findings, this problem really bugged me for a while.
My folder structure was

```
mathapp/
    - server.py  
    - configuration.py 
    - __init__.py 
    - static/ 
       - home.html  
tests/            
    - functional 
       - test_errors.py 
    - unit  
       - test_add.py
```

and pytest would complain with the `ModuleNotFoundError` and gives the hint:

> make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

I introduced a mock test file at the same level as mathsapp and tests directory. The file contained nothing. Now pytest does not complain.

Result without the file

```
$ pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\mak2006\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont
collected 1 item / 1 error

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR collecting tests/functional/test_func.py ________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\mainak\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont\tests\functional\test_func.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests\functional\test_func.py:4: in <module>
    from mathapp.service import sum
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mathapp'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR tests/functional/test_func.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================== 1 error in 0.24s ===============================
```

Results with the file

```
$ pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\mak2006\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont
collected 2 items

tests\functional\test_func.py .                                          [ 50%]
tests\unit\test_unit.py .                                                [100%]

============================== 2 passed in 0.11s ==============================
```

Comment: this worked for me after a long time with this issue.  seems like pytest is treating the project root as wherever it finds the first test file?  surely this is a bug?

Comment: Wow this worked for me. I still have to use python3 -m pytest but adding a blank test file solved the issue.

Comment: What is "a blank test file"?

Answer (score 1):

**If you run Pytest from a terminal:**

Run pytest with the `--import-mode=append` command-line flag.

Argument description in the official documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/pythonpath.html

---

*UPD:
Before I also wrote how to do the same if you use PyCharm, but community does not like extendend answers, so I removed additional information that probably was helpful to someone who have a similar issue.*

Comment: OP doesn't mention pycharm anywhere.

Comment: @DannyDannyDanny I gave a command line command for the OP. The second option is just in case, maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: I'm trying to run this from PyCharm and having this issue.  Would love that info

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the filename and the class name were exactly the same: `FrameAnalyzer.py` and `FrameAnalyzer` respectively. Once I changed the filename to `frame_analyzer.py`, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue was that my test file was named: `xxx.test.py`

it was resolved my naming the file: `xxx_test.py`

But i imagine naming it: `test_xxx.py` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was solved by fixing an import. I was importing `from project_root.tests.xxxx` and when I changed it to `from tests.xxxx` it worked. Funny thing is Pycharm didn't mark it as an error in the project tree view, I had to go into the file and only there it showed in red.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Pytest is not reading the package as a Python module while Python is (likely due to path issues). Try changing the directory of the pytest script or adding the module explicitly to your PYTHONPATH.

Or it could be that you have two versions of Python installed on your machine. Check your Python source for pytest and for the python shell that you run. If they are different (i.e. Python 2 vs 3), use `source activate` to make sure that you are running the pytest installed for the same python that the module is installed in.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a **init**.py file in your folder make a copy of the folder and delete **init**.py in that one to run your tests it works for local projects. If you need to run test regularly see if you can move your **init**.py to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]
Before directly jumping into the solution of removing/ adding `__init__.py`, we might also want to look at how the imports are been done in your classes. Actually, I lost a day playing around with just `__init__.py` thinking that might be the problem :) However, that was quite informative.

In my case, it was the wrong way of calling classes from one python class to another python class which was throwing `ImportError`. Fixed the way classes/ modules to be called and it worked like charm. Hope, this helps others as well.

And yes, for similar error, we might have different solutions depending on how the code is written. Better to spend more time on self debugging. Lesson Learnt :) Happy coding!!!

Comment: Could you give some examples of the wrong way and the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem just recently. The way it worked for me it was realizing that "setup.py" was wrong

Previously I deleted my previous `src` folder, and added a new one with other name, but I didn't change anything on the `setup.py` (newbie mistake I guess).

So pointing `setup.py` to the right packages folder did the trick for me

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="-> YOUR SERVICE NAME <-",
    extras_Require=dict(test=["pytest"]),
    packages=find_packages(where="->CORRECT FOLDER<-"),
    package_dir={"": "->CORRECT FOLDER<-"},
)
```

Also, not `init.py` in test folder nor in the root one.

Hope it helps someone =)

Best!

Comment: Voting up since it helped me and not too bad and very quick workaround if project is not organized using best practices. You saved me hours try and fail. Thanks a lot :) https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by adding the respective path to the System's Environmental Variables.

Since you are using the virtualenv, the pytest may not read the environmental variables of the virtual machine.

I also faced this issue and resolved it by adding the path to the System's Environmental Variable (PATH)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using pytest under tox. I solved it by including any submodule of my project in my setup.cfg file.

My project structure:

```
src/
    main_module
       - __init__.py
       ...
       submodule_a
           - __init__.py
           ...
       submodule_b
           - __init__.py
           ...
tests/
    - __init__.py
    - test_a.py
    ...
```

My setup.cfg file

```
...
[options]
packages = main_module, main_module.submodule_a, main_module.submodule_b
package_dir = 
    = src
...
```

Answer (score 0):

my case:

- all configurations are correct except I forgot to remove the default `my_app/tests.py`

  - After removing it, `python -m pytest tests/my_app` works fine
- pytest.ini:

```html
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=necktie_hy.settings
python_files=*/tests/*/test_*.py
python_classes=Test
```

[image: structure]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same/similar issue when trying to import a new class in my test file. In my case I moved the new import to be the last one in the test file, and then the problem went away. Not entirely sure why though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can generally recommend using **absolute paths** and running the applications and/or tests from the **root** or perhaps **parent** folder.

If someone is receiving this error in FastAPI with Uvicorn, simply run e.g.

```
uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit your conftest.py and add following lines of code:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file), '..')))
```

And if trying to run the test case through terminal, use following ex:

```
python -m pytest test_some_step_file_steps.py --html=HTML_step_file_output.html --self-contained-html
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'file' is not defined` - what should file equal to?

Comment: it should probably be __file__, see https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-script-file-path/