# pytest and pybind11: can't import c++ extension

Tags: python, pytest, pybind11

I use pybind11 to add a module `_cxx` to existing python library `liba`.
The `liba._cxx.func` doesn't exist until I compile the c++ extension and install the whole library by `setup.py`.

When I run tests in `liba/tests/test__cxx.py`, it complains that it can't import `liba._cxx`

How to solve this?

Comment: seems to solve it by removing `__init__` in the `liba/tests` folder, and then move all tests out of the `liba` folder. But I still have to test the tests a bit more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pytest cannot import module while python can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can)

Remove `__init__.py` in the test folder. That way, the test will use the `liba` installed in the system instead of `liba` within the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify the path in conftest.py

```py
import os
import sys
directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, directory)
sys.path.insert(0, directory + os.sep + "../pybewego")
sys.path.insert(0, directory + os.sep + "..")
```

pytest was also not able to handle the specific case where the c++ module has the same name as the python module. I had to follow the convention advised there:

https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1004#issuecomment-322941844

Now I can define a module that comprises both pure python and c++ extensins using pybind11 and test with pytest.