# Azure Devops pipeline pytest collection failure ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I get the following error when running an azure pipeline.
[image]

Here is the pytest part of my pipelines yaml file.

```
 steps:
  #test
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

  #test
  - script: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python -m pip install wheel
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  #test
  - script: |
      python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
      python -m spacy download de_core_news_md
  #test
  - script: |
      pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
      pytest
    displayName: 'pytest'
```

The file tat_core/criteria/checks/zw2n_test.py does not exist on my local copy of the repository. I deleted it.

How can I tell the pipeline that the file does not exist and the test does not have to be run? I assume there is some kind of caching indicated by the path /opt/hostedtoolscache. Can I empty this cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the module 'zahlwort2num' to requirements.txt. The pipeline runs now. Unused dependency in requirements.txt is a drawback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the '**`__init__.py`**' file form your project to see if it can work, like as mentioned in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can).

In addition, please also try the **`pytest`** for the same project on your local machine to see if the same issue occurs.

Comment: pytest on my local machine does not collect the file with the failing test