# ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomerIdNameSerializer' from 'contacts.api.serializers'

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have been trying to craft some unit tests for pytest. The server runs just fine when I do 'python manage.py runserver'. However, when I do 'pytest', it shows the following error:

```
============================ test session starts =============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.9, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
django: settings: tradeforce.settings.dev (from ini)
rootdir: /Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: fixture-order-0.1.3, drf-1.1.2, common-subject-1.0.5, lambda-1.2.4, django-4.1.0, assert-utils-0.2.1
collected 0 items
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 578, in _importtestmodule
INTERNALERROR>     mod = import_path(self.fspath, mode=importmode)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py", line 531, in import_path
INTERNALERROR>     importlib.import_module(module_name)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
INTERNALERROR>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
INTERNALERROR>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 170, in exec_module
INTERNALERROR>     exec(co, module.__dict__)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/tests/integration_tests.py", line 4, in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.views import CustomerCreateAPIView
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/api/views.py", line 15, in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.serializers import (
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/api/serializers.py", line 7, in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     import user.api.serializers
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/user/api/serializers.py", line 20, in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.serializers import (
INTERNALERROR> ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomerIdNameSerializer' from 'contacts.api.serializers' (/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/api/serializers.py)
INTERNALERROR>
INTERNALERROR> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
INTERNALERROR>
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 269, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 322, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_collection(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 333, in pytest_collection
INTERNALERROR>     session.perform_collect()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 634, in perform_collect
INTERNALERROR>     self.items.extend(self.genitems(node))
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 808, in genitems
INTERNALERROR>     rep = collect_one_node(node)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 457, in collect_one_node
INTERNALERROR>     ihook.pytest_collectstart(collector=collector)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_lambda/plugin.py", line 11, in pytest_collectstart
INTERNALERROR>     process_lambda_fixtures(collector.module)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 272, in module
INTERNALERROR>     return node.obj if node is not None else None
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 291, in obj
INTERNALERROR>     self._obj = obj = self._getobj()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 500, in _getobj
INTERNALERROR>     return self._importtestmodule()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/Users/woohyunan/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 608, in _importtestmodule
INTERNALERROR>     ) from e
INTERNALERROR> _pytest.nodes.Collector.CollectError: ImportError while importing test module '/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/tests/integration_tests.py'.
INTERNALERROR> Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
INTERNALERROR> Traceback:
INTERNALERROR> ../../../../.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
INTERNALERROR>     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
INTERNALERROR> contacts/tests/integration_tests.py:4: in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.views import CustomerCreateAPIView
INTERNALERROR> contacts/api/views.py:15: in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.serializers import (
INTERNALERROR> contacts/api/serializers.py:7: in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     import user.api.serializers
INTERNALERROR> user/api/serializers.py:20: in <module>
INTERNALERROR>     from contacts.api.serializers import (
INTERNALERROR> E   ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomerIdNameSerializer' from 'contacts.api.serializers' (/Users/woohyunan/projects/work/tradir/backend-app/contacts/api/serializers.py)
```

It doesn't seem to be a case of circular imports, so I am not able to pinpoint any cause for this error. The following is the structure of my 'contacts' app

```
./contacts
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   └── tests.cpython-37-pytest-6.2.2.pyc
├── admin.py
├── api
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── permissions.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── serializers.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── permissions.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── apps.py
├── management
│   └── commands
│       └── upload_country.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0002_auto_20200908_1917.py
│   ├── 0003_auto_20201105_0429.py
│   ├── 0004_accountattachment_uploader.py
│   ├── 0005_auto_20201106_0606.py
│   ├── 0006_auto_20201110_0638.py
│   ├── 0007_country_code.py
│   ├── 0008_accountattachment_key.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0002_auto_20200908_1917.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0003_auto_20201105_0429.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0004_accountattachment_uploader.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0005_auto_20201106_0606.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0006_auto_20201110_0638.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0007_country_code.cpython-37.pyc
│       ├── 0008_accountattachment_key.cpython-37.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── models.py
└── tests
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── integration_tests.cpython-37-pytest-6.2.2.pyc
    ├── factories.py
    ├── integration_tests.py
    └── unit_tests.py
```

The serializer in question is located in:
contacts/api/serializers.py

```
.
.
.
class CustomerIdNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'name', )
.
.
.
```

If this is not caused by circular imports, how does this error occur when doing tests?

Comment: Have you tried solutions posted in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can

Comment: Yes, I did. Didn't fix the issue though

Comment: `touch contacts/api/__init__.py`. Maybe other packages are affected too.

Comment: still didn't fix it..

Answer (score 1):

`from app_name import api`

```
# to use serializer
serializer=api.serializeFileName
```