# sys.path incorrect in Pytest

Tags: pytest

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to run pytest. Basically the importing was not working properly. Let me explain. The folder structure of my project is the following:

```
src
 └── api
     ├── __init__.py 
     ├── app.py
     ├── document.py
     └── tests
         ├── __init__.py
         └── test_app.py
```

And app.py has the following import statement:

```py
from document import Document
```

and obviously `test_app.py` imports `app`

Whenever I runned `pytest` from the `src` folder it would throw the following error:

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'document'
```

But once I removed the `__init__.py` file from the `api` directory it just works out of the box.

```
src
 └── api
     ├── __init__.py <--- REMOVED
     ├── app.py
     ├── document.py
     └── tests
         ├── __init__.py
         └── test_app.py
```

I have been reading many different threads, but none of them explains why this is so.

**Anyone understands why?**

Sources I have been reading through:

- [pytest cannot import module while python can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)
- [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)
- https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/pythonpath.html