# Can't run tests with brownie

Tags: python, pytest, solidity, brownie

I have one test, in the directory tests, when I run brownie test

> cannot import name 'PYTEST_COLLECT_MODULE' from '_pytest.deprecated'

python version :  3.7.11

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload the text of your error and not screenshots. And have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can