# Python module import issue when using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a Python project set up with `venv` as the virtual environment (directory structure is attached below). When I try to run the tests with `pytest` (or `python -m pytest tests` or `python -m pytest`), I run into the following exception:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/dasunpubudumal/Documents/Projects/jr101425/Python/jr101425/jr101425/tests/test_record_receipt.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_record_receipt.py:5: in <module>
    from datastore.models.models import Base, Sample
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datastore'
```

I have tried various options (like removing and adding `__init__.py` files, updating `PYTHONPATH` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can)), but none worked.

This runs perfectly fine when I run it via PyCharm; I use the same `venv` environment both in the terminal and in PyCharm.

In the test, the code header is like this:

```py
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from datastore.models.models import Base, Sample
from services.record_receipt import RecordReceipt


class TestRecordReceipt:

    ...
```

If there's anyone who could give some help in this, much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had imported modules incorrectly. For example, I should have imported `Base`, `Sample` classes from `src.datastore.models.models` instead of `datastore.models.models`.

Also, I had to update `pytest.ini` as follows:

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
python_files = test_*.py
pythonpath = .
```