# Use PyTest within a Python project using the "src" layout

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying out the one of the recommended python package layouts with the src directory.

[image]

My problem is when I run pytest from the command line my tests are not finding my python package.  I tried running from the top level of this directory and within the tests directory but still getting ModuleNotFoundError exception.  I'm running python 3.5 with pytest-3.5.0.

What is the recommend way to execute pytest from this type of python package layout?

Answer (score 11):

If you're using `py.test` to run the tests, it won't find the application as you must have not installed it. You can use `python -m pytest` to run your tests, as python will auto-add your current working directory to your PATH.

Hence, using `python -m pytest ..` would work if you're doing it in the `src` directory

The structure that I normally use is:

```
root
├── packagename
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
└── tests
    └── ...
```

This way when I simply run `python -m pytest` in the root directory it works fine. Read more at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34140498/1755083

Second option, if you still want to run this with `py.test` you can use:

```
PYTHONPATH=src/ py.test
```

and run it from the root. This simply adds the src folder to your PYTHONPATH and now your tests will know where to find the `packagename` package.

The third option is to use pip with `-e` to install your package in the editable mode. This creates a link to the `packagename` folder and installs it with pip - so any modification done in `packagename` is immediately reflected in pip's installation (as it is a link). The issue with this is that you need to redo the installation if you move the repo and need to keep track of which one is installed if you have more than 1 clones/packages.

Comment: The whole idea of putting the package into `src/` is to _prevent_ it from being imported. You want to test the installed package, not the development folder.

Comment: One reason for using `src` is to isolate the code for deployment management. It may not even be a package. To allow running tests against the repo code you can add the root directory to `PYTHONPATH` and this can be done in the `.venv/bin/activate` script to make it seamless.

Answer (score 6):

Your layout looks OK and is the today recommended.

But I assume your problem are the `import` in your `test_*.py` files. You shouldn't take care about from where to import your package in you unittests; just import them.

## Install in Development Mode via `--editable`

How could this be done? You have to "install" your package in [Developement Mode](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html). Use the `--editable` option of `pip`. In that case not a real package is build and installed but only symlinks are used to expose your package folder (the source in developer version) to the operating system as it would be a real release package.

Now your unittest never need to care about where the package is installed and how to import it. Just import it because the package is known to the system.

**Note**: This is the today recommended way. Other "solutions" hacking around with manipulating `sys.path` or environment variables like `PYTHONPATH` are just from Python's early days and should be avoided today.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea behind the `src` layout is to isolate the package code notably from the tests. The best way I see here is to install your package and test it as it will be delivered to future users.

Much more suitable for development. No need for hacks like `import src` or to modify the `PYTHONPATH`.

- Create a virtual environment
- Build your package
- Install your package manually
- Install your test dependencies (possibly different from the package dependencies)
- Run `pytest` in the main directory

It works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents:

Don't use `py.test`, use `pytest`. The `py.test` is an old and deprecated command.

Notice Windows users; you may or may not have `PYTHONPATH` defined on your system. 
In such a case, I used the following commands to run tests:

```
set PYTHONPATH=src
pytest
```

To examine the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%
src
```

And the directory structure on containing `src` folder:

```
setup.py
src
    utils
        algo.py
        srel.py
        __init__.py
tests
    algo_test.py
    srel_test.py
    __init__.py
```

Finally, the documentation says that you might omit the `__init__.py` files. Removing them worked for me in this case.

Comment: Importing `src` violates the idea of the "src" layout.