# Gitlab CI Python run test - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, gitlab-ci

I saw a lot of questions about importing modules error but I could not manage to solve the problem with Gitlab CI pipeline.

My project structure:

```
├───config
├───docs
├───src
    __init__.py
│   ├───dataset
        __init__.py
│   ├───exceptions
│   ├───resources
│   └───utils
        __init__.py
└───tests
    __init__.py
    └───resources
__init__.py
```

I would like to run tests using pytest.
I invoke this command `python -m pytest -p no:cacheprovider` or using unittest
'python -m unittest discover -v' from root directory and also tried to invoke from test directory. In both cases I have a problem with importing class from dataset module. What's interesting, I have two tests file.

First file imports:

```
import os import unittest

from src.utils.FileManager import FileManager
```

Second imports:

```
from src.dataset.DatasetHelper import DatasetHelper
```

The first file is passing but the second is failing  with error:

> from dataset import DatasetHelper ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'dataset'

So the thing is that other modules like utils from src are imported correctly, only the dataset has a problem. I am struggling with this a few days and I completely out of ideas. I also tried to change instead of from dataset to from src.dataset. It didn't work. I can run tests in PyCharm by clicking right mous button and just run tests but not on CI environment.

What I tried:

- Add modules to $PYTHONPATH like

  ```
  sys.path.insert(0, "/builds/USER/PROJECT/src/dataset") 
  sys.path.insert(0, "/builds/USER/PROJECT/src") 
  sys.path.insert(0, "/builds//USER/PROJECT/tests")
  ```

The content of PYTHONPATH before adding it was:

```
Current $PYTHONPATH: ['/builds/USER/PROJECT/config', '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

The first module in list is config because I run script from this directory to add above modules to path. Doesn't Help

- Run test command from root directory and add prefix `src` to imports in tests directory. Doesn't Help

Comment: Check out this question for different solutions for the `No module named` issue: [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada). You have clobbered your project with unnecessary `__init__.py` files, also the `sys.path` manipulations are not necessary.

Comment: The right way to do it is to have a `setup.py` and do a `python setup.py develop` in your CI. This will ensure your library is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from dataset import DatasetHelper
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataset'

Either in `src.__init__` or more proabably in `src.dataset.__init__` there is the import statement `from dataset import DatasetHelper`. You have to rewrite it as `from src.dataset import…`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a relative import in your `__init__.py` file that's inside the **tests** directory.

The syntax depends on the current location as well as the current location of the module,package, or object you're trying to import. Here are some examples:

```
from .some_module import some_class
from ..some_package import some_function
from . import some_class
```

Source: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/