# Folder structure and import problems with pytest

Tags: python, python-import, pytest

Imagine a simple folder structure:

```
my_folder/
    __init__.py
    funcs.py
    tests/
        test_funcs.py
```

**funcs.py:**

```
def f():
    return 2
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from funcs import f
```

**test_funcs.py:**

```
from funcs import f

def test_f():
    assert f() == 2
```

It's one of the suggested ways in the documentation:
https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/directory_structure.html

But when I run pytest from `my_folder`:

```
tests/test_funcs.py:1: in <module>
    from funcs import f
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcs'
```

It's strange because I would have thought that `pytest` sets the path from where it's been running so those kinds of errors don't come up without dealing with it manually.

The documentation doesn't gave any indication about this either...  They're just saying :

> Typically you can run tests by pointing to test directories or modules:
>
> ```
> pytest tests/test_appmodule.py      # for external test dirs
> pytest src/tests/test_appmodule.py  # for inlined test dirs
> pytest src                          # run tests in all below test directories
> pytest                              # run all tests below current dir
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: your `__init__.py` you should have `from .funcs import f` -- you are making a package-relative import

Comment: @AnthonySottile I considered that solution, as well. Unfortunately, running pytest with that modification still yields the same error: `E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcs'`

Comment: oh also your test file should have `from my_folder.funcs import f` -- `$ python -m pytest -q my_folder` ==> `1 passed in 0.01 seconds`

Comment: That works! (when it is run outside of my_folder). But running `pytest` within my_folder still fails

Comment: This proves that the documentation is missing something! You're even providing another way to run the tests! The doc just says `pytest`...

Comment: At the end of the day, this has nothing to do with pytest, it's just related to how python import statements work. Always use `-m` and almost everything should be okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very simple way:

1. Empty out `__init__.py`
2. From a level above `my_folder` run `python -m pytest` or `python -m pytest tests` (but not `pytest`)

**EXPLANATION:** Running a module with the `-m` option will include it in the `PYTHONPATH`, so everything related to the import statements will be solved smoothly.

Comment: That still produces the same ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score -1):

The test file `test_funcs.py` must be run from the directory where the module `funcs` is located in order for the import to be successful.

As a workaround, you can modify [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), which determines the interpeter's search path for modules.

`test_funcs.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/Yahya/Desktop/my_folder')

from funcs import f

def test_f():
    assert f() == 2
```

Comment: Just want to note: the path `"/Users/Yahya/Desktop/my_folder"` is just an example. If you would like to determine the absolute path of my_folder, you can open a terminal, `cd my_folder`, and `pwd`.

Comment: I know about this workaround, but are you saying that the documentation is wrong, or at the very least obviously incomplete? (see the added quote)

Comment: monkeypatching `sys.path` is almost never the right way

Comment: The only other way to be able to use `funcs` in `tests/test_funcs.py` is to move `__init__.py` (as is) from `my_folder` to `tests`. Running pytest from my_folder after this transfer will result in a passing test. Unfortunately, though, the documentation specifically advises against it: "You shouldn’t have __init__.py files in your test directories"