# How can I import some functions and classes from modules into test file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

How can I import  *NestedValueError* class &  *validate_item* function from modules into test.py ?

Should I use conftest.py as a mediator between modules and tests file or something?

```
# /modules/errors.py 

class EmptyValueError(Exception):
      pass
```

---

```
#/modules/validate_item.py
def validate_item():
    pass
```

---

```
#/tests/test.py

import pytest 

def test_item_validate_exception_nested_value():
    with pytest.raises(EmptyValueError):
        validate_item({})
```

Comment: How can you have files in `/modules` while having code directly in the same path?

Comment: you're right. I changed it.

Comment: Why would you think it's different from any other import ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
from modules.errors import EmptyValueError 
from modules.validate_item import validate_item
```

But be sure to run pytest in `/`, [with the following command](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html):

```
python3 -m pytest test/
```

From pytest documentation (linked above):

> This is almost equivalent to invoking the command line script `pytest [...]` directly, except that calling via `python` will also add the current directory to `sys.path`.