# Python 3 inter-project imports do not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, importerror

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
project/
    README.md
    project/
        foobar/
            foo.py
        tests/
            test_foo.py
```

`test_foo` is just `from foobar import foo` and when I run `py.test` or just `python3 tests/test_foo.py` from the `project` subdirectory, I get a `No module named foobar` error. I tried the other answers here such as adding `..` to `sys.path`, using relative imports, none work, except when running `python3 test_foo.py` inside `tests` with `sys.path.append('..')`.

Comment: You need an `__init__.py` in a directory if you wish to import it as a module.

Comment: can you write the code?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog not since 3.3 AFAIK. and i did try it, no difference.

Comment: @Ali.Turkkan what code?

Comment: Codes written in foo.py and test_foo.py

Comment: [`touch project/project/conftest.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610630/2650249)

Comment: alright, this fixes the import problem. However, if i have another file `bar.py` with the `Bar` class, it can't import that from `foo.py`. Executing `foo.py` raises no errors.

Answer (score 0):

First make a package from your project and install it.

If installed, you can simply use absolute links, started with your package name:

```
from project import foobar
from project.foobar import foo
```

Another way - use intra-package links (no modification to `sys.path` needed):

**test_foo.py**

```
from .. import foobar
```

Comment: The problem is that my project is not a library, so i'm not making a standard distutils setup.py

Answer (score 0):

### foo.py

```
def test():
    print("test")
```

### test_foo.py

```
import os
import sys

runPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(runPath, ".."))

from foobar import foo

foo.test()
```

### Output

```
test
```

Comment: two issues, adding paths to `sys.path` is "generally not recommended" and it would be cumbersome to paste that into every test file.