# pytest failed to import local module (importing built-in module instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I have the following Python 2.7 simplified project structure:

```
project/
  ├── libs/
  |     └── zipfile.py
  ├── tests/
  |     ├── __init__.py
  |     └── test_hello.py
  ├── hello.py
  └── main.py
```

I want this project to use the patched version of one of Python built-in modules (which in this example is `zipfile`) located in `libs`. Note that this is an external requirement, and I cannot change the project structure.

---

Below are the simplified implementation of each file:

**libs/zipfile.py**

```
def is_zipfile(filename):
    return "Patched zipfile called"
```

**tests/test_hello.py**

```
from hello import hello

def test_hello():
    assert hello() == "Patched zipfile called"
```

**hello.py**

```
import os
import sys

libs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs"))
if libs_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, libs_path)

import zipfile

def hello():
    print(zipfile.__file__)  # to check which zipfile module is imported
    result = zipfile.is_zipfile("some_path")
    return result
```

**main.py**

```
from hello import hello

def main():
    print(hello())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

When running the program directly (`python main.py`), I got the expected result:

```
/home/project/libs/zipfile.pyc
Patched zipfile called
```

However, when running pytest with `project` as the working directory (`pytest -s`), it failed:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.pyc
================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_hello __________________________________

    def test_hello():
>       assert hello() == "Patched zipfile called"
E       assert False == 'Patched zipfile called'
E        +  where False = hello()

tests/test_hello.py:4: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.13 seconds ===========================
```

I've tried a couple solutions presented in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10253826/4879957), such as running `python -m pytest`, but none has worked for me. Is there a way to successfully run this test in a non-hacky way?

Comment: IS this definitely the setup you have? When I copy this structure it fails with `pytest -s: tests/test_hello.py: ImportError: No module named hello`

Comment: @match Woops, thank you for spotting it out, my tests directory actually has `__init__.py` in it. I'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your patched `zipfile` module is not being imported is it has already been imported before the test is started (likely by pytest or one of its dependencies)

I verified this by putting this at the top of `hello.py`:

```
if 'zipfile' in sys.modules:
    raise AssertionError('zipfile already imported')
```

I then get:

```
$ ./venv/bin/python -mpytest tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /tmp/x, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                   

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_hello.py _____________________
tests/test_hello.py:1: in <module>
    from hello import hello
hello.py:5: in <module>
    raise AssertionError('zipfile already imported')
E   AssertionError: zipfile already imported
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.14 seconds ============================
```

You could delete `zipfile` from `sys.modules` and then perhaps your copy would be the only one imported:

```
sys.modules.pop('zipfile', None)
```

That said, all of this seems like potentially a bad idea as anyone who has already imported that module will have access to the old `zipfile` and stubbing out stdlib implementation has high potential to break third party libraries which don't expect that.

You might have ~slightly better luck by patching out individual methods on the `zipfile` module directly (using something like `mock.patch.object(zipfile, 'fn', ...)`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed insight! Accepting this as the answer. I’ll think of a way to solve it based on your suggestion.