# Splitting Tests and code into different folders throws a "ModuleNotFoundError"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to learn how to work with pytest module.

I have a package called function1 with init.py and code.py files.

There is another folder "tests" with test_code.py file.

When code.py and test_code.py are in the same folder it works fine. But when I try to split them up, running pytest returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'function1'

I can create another py file and import function1.code and calling on any function within the code.py file works. So its not a problem with python not being able to find the module.

What am I missing?

Comment: What command are you using to run pytest?

Comment: Running "pytest" is what causes the error. I just learned that running "python -m pytest" works. But I don't understand why?

Comment: That is strange--it must be a quirk of how the `pytest` command itself is written that makes packages in the working directory undiscoverable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)