# New Python project can't run test due to "ImportError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Today I tried to work in some exercises and I created two files, the '~/bankocr/bank.py' and '~/bankocr/tests/test_working.py'

And when I tried to execute 'pytest' in the console I have the next error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '~/bankocr/tests/test_bank.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_bank.py:2: in <module>
    from bank import size_of
E   ImportError: No module named bank
```

I didn't see the difference in the files using an IDE to create a new project, but still, one works and the other don't.

Did I forget something?

Comment: why is it saying that the module gets imported from `~/bank/` insteand of `~/bankocr/`? Did you try `from test_bank import size_of`

Comment: Maybe it's an error, sorry, it's because I tried it in two separate folders to compare

Comment: Please study the proper way of placing your module. Using a relative path import will work but it is ugly and not usable.

Comment: The real solution is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971504/11593047

Answer (score 0):

`bank.py` and `test_bank.py` are not in the same folder. You can try to use relative import,

```py
from ..bank import size_of
```

Comment: I tried first with the files in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

This error is merely based on the pythonpaths.You should introduce that path in your pytest.ini/tox.ini file.

Please follow the steps below:-

(1) Create pytest.ini file in your parent directory.

(2) Edit in the following ways:-

```
[pytest]
python_paths = .  ~/bankocr/
```

Execute the code then. I anticipate that you would not observe the error after creating the above file.

Reference:-

https://github.com/bigsassy/pytest-pythonpath/blob/master/pytest.ini

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can run the tests as,

```
python -m bankocr.tests
```

It will run all your test modules inside the tests folder. Also, add **init**.py at '~/bankocr/' to import your other modules such as bank.py