# Python can't import Custom module

Tags: python

In my workspace , the directory structure is like this:

```
F:
  `-- src
     |-- lib
     |   `-- base.py
     `-- tests
         `-- test_modulexx
             `-- test_module_001.py
```

In the file `test_module_001.py` , I import the `lib` module.

test_module_001.py:

```
import os
from lib.base import BaseTestCase
```

Sometimes when I run it in the folder F:\src. it raise a error:

```
File "F:\src\tests\test_modulexx\test_module_001.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lib.base import BaseTestCase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

If you have met the same error and you have solved it, Can you share it to me ?
And also, I want to know why it doesn't work. Let's end the problem thoroughly.

Comment: have you added a ```__init__.py``` to your ```lib``` dir?

Comment: *How* do you run ``test_module_001.py``? Is ``lib`` installed? Is it in ``PYTHONPATH``?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada

Comment: Thank everyone. I'll see all the solution to solve it .

Comment: PS. I run it in the console. and the console is started in the folder F:\src .when I open a python console and execute 'import lib'. it works.

Answer (score 0):

I hava tried to debug this and found something maybe helpful to it.

when I start python console . and import the module `lib` ,it works.then I check the sys.path, the result is like this.

```
>> import lib
>> import sys
>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', '', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

the first element in the list is `''`. then I set breakpoint in the python file before it import the module `lib`.

file test_module_001.py:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
import lib
```

then I execute python tests\test_modulexx\test_module_001.py in the windows console and print `sys.path`

```
>f:\src\tests\test_modulexx\test_module_001.py(2)<module>()
->import lib
(Pdb)import sys
(Pdb)sys.path
['F:\\src\\tests\\test_modulexx', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
(Pdb)import lib
*** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

the first element in `sys.path` has been changed. now it is `F:\\src\\tests\\test_modulexx`. I add `''` to `sys.path` and `import lib`. it works.

```
(Pdb)sys.path.append('')
(Pdb)import lib
(Pdb)
```

I think the reason is that Scope of Python importing module is defined in the sys.path. and the `''` means the current path.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have added the required `__init__.py` files for your modules.
See: [Working with Modules in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/modules-in-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1028688&gclid=CjwKCAjwm_P5BRAhEiwAwRzSO2gdeL61nxmFkGNS_5TCEG_z4hjWzXXAZf8lV2pq1o6lTy4cS0Y0OhoCAPoQAvD_BwE)