# Pytest PATH src/, tests/ structure

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have the following directory structure with my python project.

```
Project root
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── libA.py
│   │   └── libB.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_app.py
```

`app.py` has `from lib.libA import LibA` statement.

`test_app.py` has the import statement `from src.app import App`,

When I run pytest, I can make `test_app.py` to import by adding `__init__.py` to `src` folder, but when `app.py` is importing `from lib.libA import LibA`, it fails in pytest.

```
ImportError while importing test module '/projectroot/tests/test_app.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_app.py:6: in <module>
    from src.app import App
src/lib/libA.py:5: in <module>
    from lib.libB import LibB
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

So the import chain is something like `tests/test_app.py` -> `src/app.py` -> `src/lib/libA.py` -> `src/lib/libB.py`. App needs to import libA, and libA imports libB.

One way I can fix is by doing `sys.path.append("src/")` to `tests/__init__.py`, but it does not look like a standard way to me.

**Is there any correct/better way to fix this issue?**

**Edit**:
I would like to understand if my directory structure is incorrect, or am I importing the wrong way. I understand I could use tricks like `sys.path.append()` or modify `PYTHONPATH`, but I am looking for a "better" way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for your comment, but no. I am aware of the answer stated in that question, which I listed in mine as one solution that I can fix. I would like to know if my structure is incorrect, or am I importing the wrong way.

Comment: You have seen that there is more than one answer to that question, right?

Comment: You are not using the imports right. First, the `src` directory is usually used to hide the code from the interpreter, so you are forced to install your project in order to test it. Now, you are using `src` as a package (by putting an `__init__.py` into it), so either `from src.lib.libB import LibB` (absolute), or `from .lib.libB import LibB` (relative).

Comment: So the correct way is to install the project and run the tests on the installed version? My project needs to install to `/opt/companyname/projectname`, in this case I would still need to do `sys.path.append` right?