# how to use Streamlit and Pytest in the same project

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, streamlit

When I try to use Pytest and Streamlit in the same project, things go wrong in the module imports, and I'm not sure how to handle it.

My directory is as follows:

```
repo
├── main.py
├── app.py
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── util_a.py
└── tests
     ├── __init__.py
     └── test_a.py
```

The `app.py` file includes the next import line:

```py
import utils.util_a 
...
```

Now, the streamlit application runs as expected with the following line:
`streamlit run repo/app.py`

But while I run `py.test` I received an error message:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

If I replace the import line in `app.py` as follow:

```py
import repo.utils.util_a 
...
```

Surprisingly, Pytest runs as expected but the Streamlit application returns the next error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'repo'
```

What is the root cause of that error, and how can I deal with it? How can I use Pytest and Streamlit in the same project without causing an import conflict?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610630/11079284
That answer about `conftest.py` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `conftest.py` file in the `repo` solves the problem. Now, the directory looks like this:

```
repo
├── main.py
├── app.py
├── conftest.py
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── util_a.py
└── tests
     ├── __init__.py
     └── test_a.py
```

More details in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610630/11079284)