# ModuleNotFoundError importing helper from main

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I'm getting the following error when try to use `pytest` to run my tests:

```
tests/main_test.py:1: in <module>
    from src.main import main
src/main.py:1: in <module>
    from string_helper import string_sum
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string_helper'
```

My project is very simple, here is the structure:

[image]

**src/main.py**

```
from string_helper import string_sum

def main():
  a = 2
  b = 1
  r = string_sum(a, b)
  #print(r)
  return r

if __name__ == "__main__":
  r = main()
  print(r)
```

**src/string_helper.py**

```
def string_sum(a, b):
  return str(a + b)
```

**tests/main_test.py**

```
from src.main import main

def test_string_sum():
  r = main(1, 2)
  assert type(r) is str
  assert r == "3"
```

Here is the repl.it if you want to run it in web browser: https://replit.com/@gmunumel/TestCasesExample?v=1. Run `pytest -v` and install the latest version of the package. You should see the error.

Comment: One way - you could put the code inside a module (/src/mymodule/main.py), and use absolute imports (`mymodule.main`,`mymodule.string_helper`). When running tests, add `src` to `sys.path` and import from `mymodule`.

Comment: @Peter, thanks but didn't work for me. I found an easiest solution here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610630/992347](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50610630/992347)